# Merging one query as parameter into another query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

How to combine Query2 In Query1 as second parameter along with the existing Select count(*) statement with an or condition.

-------------------Query 1--Main Query to retireve sources & table count--------

```
Select
pathSuffix, 
              (Select count(*) from Sources with(nolock)
              where level = 2 and 
              (
                     (parent like '%raw%' and type= 'DIRECTORY' AND  parent like '/prod/' + s.pathSuffix + '/raw') or
                     (parent like '%archive%' and type='DIRECTORY' and parent like '/prod/' + s.pathSuffix + '/archive')
              )) as filecount, 
modificationTime,
owner, 
type               
from Sources s with(nolock) where level = 0
order by pathSuffix
```

----------Query2--Gets the Count of Snapshot_rpx files as 495----------------

```
select Count(distinct(SUBSTRING(pathSuffix,
                           CHARINDEX('-', pathSuffix)+1,
                           LEN(pathSuffix)- (CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(pathSuffix)) + CHARINDEX('-', pathSuffix)))))
from Sources s with(nolock)
where parent like '/prod/snapshot_rpx/archive%' and  type='FILE' and level=2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-query:

```
select Count(distinct(SUBSTRING(pathSuffix, CHARINDEX('-', pathSuffix)+1, LEN(pathSuffix)- (CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(pathSuffix)) + CHARINDEX('-', pathSuffix))))), (Select count(*) from Sources with(nolock) where level = 2 and ( (parent like '%raw%' and type= 'DIRECTORY' AND parent like '/prod/' + s.pathSuffix + '/raw') or (parent like '%archive%' and type='DIRECTORY' and parent like '/prod/' + s.pathSuffix + '/archive') )) as filecount, modificationTime, owner, type
from Sources s with(nolock) where level = 0 order by pathSuffix) from Sources s with(nolock) where parent like '/prod/snapshot_rpx/archive%' and type='FILE' and level=2
```

Comment: I am getting errors with your new code.Can someone help me in fixing this issue.

Comment: Paste the query you are running and the output it produces.